# Выдает ошибку Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php

При подключении выдает ошибки так и не понял что здесь не так , вроде правильный синтаксис.

```
 `
Notice: Undefined index: log in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tech_user/con_data_ajax/connect_ajax_data_users.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: login in /opt/lampp/htdocs/tech_user/con_data_ajax/connect_ajax_data_users.php on line 12
`
```

**ФАЙЛ ГДЕ ЭТА ОШИБКА**

```
    <?php
include ('database/connect_my_admin.php');
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$answer = '{"id":"0", "name":"xxx"}';

if(($_GET['log']=="tech_user") AND ($_GET['pasw']=="111")){
    mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT tab_1 SET pass='111',login='tech_user'  WHERE id='1'");  
    echo  '{"id":"1", "name":"Копыча"}';

}

if(($_GET['login']=="tech_user") AND ($_GET['pass']=="222")){
    mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT tab_1 SET pass='222',login='tech_user'  WHERE id='2'");      
    echo  '{"id":"2", "name":"Порхун"}';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто. Массив `$_GET` не содержит значений с ключами `log` и `login`.

Чтобы узнать, что он содержит, можно вывести весь массив командой `var_dump($_GET)`

Если эти параметры необязательны, то код должен это учитывать

```
if (isset($_GET['log']) && ($_GET['log']=="tech_user") && ($_GET['pasw']=="111")){
```

Или для PHP 7

```
if ((($_GET['log'] ?? '')=="tech_user") && ($_GET['pasw']=="111")){
```